# Meizu m3 note started lagging because of Google play services

Tags: google-play-store, google

Recently, my meizu phone started lagging, and after a while, I decided to reinstall my system. After a couple of reinstallations, i realised, the problem was in google services, because my phone started to lag exactly after google services installation. And the worst thing is that I can't use any of 50% of my apps anymore, because they all need a GS to work.

P.S. I installed GS with google installer from meizu app store.

Comment: The same problem with me. Try to install older version of Google play service, I used this version of play service, https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/meizu/google-apps-installer/google-apps-installer-4-4-2-release/google-apps-installer-4-4-2-android-apk-download/download/

Comment: @bagustris did it work for you ? Because if I install the older version of GS, it will probably update itself to the latest version.

Comment: This also happened to me. It took me 3 days to find out that google play service caused the lagging. I though my meizu m3 note was infected by some virusses. I uninstalled google Play service and the lag was gone.

Comment: @Incognitus yes it works for me. Turn off your auto update on Meizu app store, that is the problem.

Comment: @bagustris Man, u saved my phone, thanks a lot))) Can you copy your answer in answer section, so I can point it as the best one ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is caused by Meizu app store that continuously updating google play service infinitely. So, try the following steps:

1. Turn off your auto update on Meizu app store by tapping App store > profile (top right) > setting > App store auto update.
2. Install older version of Google app installer, for example is [here](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/meizu/google-apps-installer/google-apps-installer-4-4-2-release/google-apps-installer-4-4-2-android-apk-download/download/).

Those steps work for me.